# Android Studio shows warning everywhere, all the imports shows yellow warnings, all the class names including shows a yellow warning, how to stop that

Tags: android, android-studio

When I hover on the default import statement of **"import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
"** even then Android Studio shows the warning "**Single class import 'import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;'** ",

even "**setContentView**(R.layout.activity_main);" shows a warning saying **"Instance method call 'setContentView' is not qualified with 'this'"**

and probably what ever I write Android Studio has some knowledge to share. How do I remove all the **UNNECESSARY** warnings.

Below is a screenshot of the event log.
[This is the link for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvBwT.png)

I believe that there is something to do with the JDK but I would really love to know the cause of the problem.

Comment: Does this happen with all the projects? I mean, did you try creating a new project and check if this error also exists there or not?

Comment: Yes, this is a new project, also you can check out the screenshot  it clearly shows that the project is a new one. Also, want to tell you that I uninstalled the studio and then again redownloaded it, but still we're here.

Comment: There should be an option that android studio gives in order to suppress those warnings, I think you should look for that and check what type of suppression does it provide. For eg. there are suppressions like, "@SuppressLint(Deprecated)" that suppress the warnings that emerges due to use of deprecated components. :D

Comment: I went to ** File->Settings->Editor->Inspections **  and unchecked all the Java warnings from there, yes it does the job and removes all the warnings but in my humble opinion this is just a temporary fix. Now Android studio shows no error whatsoever and that was not the main aim, I am missing out on a ton of excellent suggessions that way. Need another solution :) @AbhishekChoudhary

Comment: No no no... please revert your changes and then hover over the warnings, then click on the "more options" button. Then choose the option that says "Suppress using.......". Doing this will add a line of code that will suppress a certain type of warning. And then check for the type of suppression it is providing.